# best practices for multiple spring controller.should i follow functionality based or user based?

Tags: spring, rest, controller

I am planning to split my exiting spring controller into multiple ones.
What are the best practices while following this approach.
Should they be split based on the functionality?or by users who will perform the actions?
And also should i change the mapping URL ?or use the same URL for both the controller, as the method level i will have a different mapping URL again.

Any reply will highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good practices related to your question...

1. Controller specific to a module .
2. Having mapping url based on the controller

   eg.) PatientController -- >  ../../patient/save  and  ../../patient/edit

   /patient is for the controller

   /save and /edit defines the method
3. You can add activity log for monitoring the type of users and their operations.

Comment: @Boss.Thx for your reply.I am planning to follow above approach.can u please share any URL giving details about best practices.

Comment: Above answer is for your question,but the real best in the link http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/01/25/spring-xml-configuration-best-practices.html

Comment: @hanmayya accept the answer if this is what you are looking for